# Run java project in docker and using a local IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, docker, intellij-idea

I have a java project inside a docker container that imports libraries and using files that are inside that same container.

How can I use an IDE to run this project?

I want to run the project inside the container, but also developing the project using Eclipse or IntelliJ on my local machine. Is this possible ?

Comment: can you post your Dockerfile? Also what IDE are you using? Normally you can map you project as a volume and then build and run everything inside the container. Another idea is to have only the dependencies from the container made available to your IDE.

Comment: Why do you need to debug it inside the container?  You can develop the application locally, and once you’ve hand tested it, it’s JUnit tests pass, and so on, COPY the .jar file into an image that only has a JRE, no development or debugging tools.

Comment: Attaching your project folder (of the local machine) as a volume to the docker container should help. That way you can open the project in any IDE of your choice and also be able to run it inside a container as you wish.

Comment: @DavidMaze My container has Hadoop installed. For now I'm programming using vim.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html) is what you're after:

Note, this took me around 7 seconds to find on google. It's usually best to try there first.